# Python Tools for Visual Studio 2012. Missing Python on tools/option window

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

After following the guide on [This page from codeplex](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20interpreters%20&%20libraries%20-%20details&referringTitle=Home), I'm not able to see the Python option on my tools/option window.  I believe the only deviations I took from the guide are:

- Distributions : Didn't install the activestate python, since I already have Python installed.
- Interpreters  : Installed  only IronPython 2.7

After a few installs/reinstalls,  I still can't see it working...What could I be missing? Or should I go back to visual studio 2010?

Comment: The link in your question is dead. :O

Comment: @Zarles Krieger Sadly they deleted it =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer?  It bypasses a lot of the possible errors when installing the framework, checks for dependencies, etc:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx